# How to capture a user's full name from their text input using watson's assistant dialog?

Tags: watson-dialog, watson-assistant

I(as a newbie) am setting up a messenger chatbot using IBM's watson.
I want to get a user to type in their information and I save it as a variable.

For example:

```
chatbot:  What is your name?
User: I am Angella Naigaga
chatbot saves "Angella Naigaga"
Chatbot: Thank you Angella
```

Comment: Are you using Slots?

Comment: I'm not familiar with slots. But so far I have managed to use input.text though I can't say I really know what I am doing.

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-slots I recommend following through one of the tutorials. Obtaining names, locations, etc. is a very common tasks and there are samples in the documentation. Else, add a specific code problem to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant supports regular expressions - both in entities and also directly accessible from `input.text` field.

For example this expression will set up name variable to capture names consisting of two words with optional `"I am "` before that.

```
"context" : {
    "name" : "<?input.text.extract('(I am )?(\\w+ \\w+)',2)?>"
}
```

More documentation about regexp and also a webpage where one can try how the regexp matches is here:

https://regex101.com/

Note that this is quite technical and as data_henrik suggests some slot tutorials might be a better bet.